# SQLiteWinRT and access from background task

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, mutex

There's a few posts that I've looked at dealing with synchronisation between a background scheduled task and the foreground app (this is with Windows Phone 8). The problem is that potentially different processes can be accessing/editing the  `IsolatedSettingsStorage.ApplicationSettings`or my local SQLite DB, if it isn't synchronised correctly there could be corruption issues.

I'm using a Mutex to protect access to `IsolatedSettingsStorage.ApplicationSettings` like so:

```
    public static string GetApplicationSetting(string Key)
{
    using (Mutex Mutex = new Mutex(false, "ApplicationSettingsMutex"))
    {
        String Result = "";

        Mutex.WaitOne();

        try
        {
            if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains(Key))
            {
                Result = (string)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[Key];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            Mutex.ReleaseMutex();                
        }

        return Result;
    }
}

public static void SetApplicationSetting(string Key, string Value)
{
    using (Mutex Mutex = new Mutex(false, "ApplicationSettingsMutex"))
    {
        Mutex.WaitOne();

        try
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[Key] = Value;
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            Mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do something similar when accessing my local db, but I can't work out how the best way of doing so. What exactly does the Mutex have to protect? Only writing to the db?

```
                    // Set AzurePk for the local Record
                using (var UpdateRecord = await db.PrepareStatementAsync("UPDATE Record SET AzurePk = ? WHERE Id = ?"))
                {
                    UpdateRecord.BindTextParameterAt(1, NewRecord.Id);
                    UpdateRecord.BindIntParameterAt(2, NewRecord.RecordId);

                    await UpdateRecord.StepAsync();
                }
```

That's some example code of me updating the SQLite database from my scheduled task, it'd be easy enough to surround that code with a Mutex, but in the foreground app there are lots of different areas where I'm querying the database, it could get messy really quickly.

I had thought about making a copy of the local .db file and then my background task would only work on the copy, that would work but only if I was reading from it, not if I had to insert or update.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So this is my take (faith) on the situation... As I'm going to be accessing a sqlite datastore from a background agent and foreground application

- http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5
  "SQLite uses reader/writer locks to control access to the database." It says this is unreliable with windows systems but I'm not sure if this applies to WinRT
- if you specify the option SQLITE_OPEN_NOMUTEX then that opens the connection in multi-threaded mode  http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html.  If I understand this correctly then Sqlite uses Mutex's internally when accessing shared resources.

The first point I don't hold much faith in as I don't know how well this reader/writer lock works in WinRT. From what I can tell from the sqlite documentation if you open the connections in multi-threaded mode then you are safe to just access the DB from your background and foreground. Access to shared resources will be protected via internal Mutex's... There are other things to be aware of though if you open the DB in multi threaded mode...

For example: "Multi-thread. In this mode, SQLite can be safely used by multiple threads provided that no single database connection is used simultaneously in two or more threads. "

I'm in the process of moving over from IsolatedStorage to using Akavache for everything which uses sqlite as it's back end and it opens the sqlite connection in multi-threaded mode
https://github.com/akavache/Akavache/blob/master/Akavache.Sqlite3/SQLiteAsync.cs

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually solved my problem by simplifying my app functionality. Using the app launching/closing/activated/deactivated event handlers in App.cs (for Windows Phone) I would add or remove my scheduled task to ensure it would only fire if the app was closed or deactivated. For my Android port with Xamarin I'm using RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks to track when the app is visible/in the foreground and if it is I don't allow the background task to access my SQLite DB. Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Did you find that it was necessary to create this kind of separation? Like without it were you getting issues of corruption in SQL Lite?

Comment: To be honest I didn't really try, it's difficult to simulate concurrent DB queries... I wasn't happy launching the app into the wild without including some kind of DB concurrency protection. And it wasn't a problem for me if my background task was delayed because the app was in use (on Windows Phone the task only fires every 30 minutes). Cheers